# How to publish 1434 UDP port through ISA SERVER 2006?

Tags: sql, sql-server, isaserver

I have an issue with remote application connection through ISA server:

The application should connect to Application server trough Isa server but the application tries to connect 46.x.x.x over `UDP 1434`  but ISA server cannot publish `1434 UDP` like `1433 TCP` port.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
   at Startup.DataLayer.vwAccYearAdapter.GetvwAccYearSWhere(String WhereSQL)
   at Startup.Forms.Login.LoadData()
   at Startup.Forms.Login..ctor()
   at Startup.Program.Main()
```

Comment: I know nothing about ISA server but it seems the application is trying to connect to a SQL Server named instance using the instance name, which uses UDP port 1434 to get the instance TCP port. You can avoid that by specifying the named instance TCP port instead of instance name in the database connection string.

Comment: @DanGuzman, Thanks for your pay attention. this application is not developed by my self. and as you said it requires UDP 1434 to connect database server. changing connection string I think is not possible.